# Why is the ASP.NET routing engine ignoring files?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

I have a class that implements both `IHttpHandler` and `IRouteHandler`:

```
  public class CustomHandler : IHttpHandler,IRouteHandler
  {
    public bool IsReusable
    {
      get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
      context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
      context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
      return this;
    }
  }
```

In the Application_Start method I try to register my handler with route:

```
Route route = new Route("dav/{*Pathinfo}", new CustomHandler());
RouteTable.Routes.Add(route);
```

Everything is cool until I call with this kind Url:
- `http://localhost:63428/dav/asdadsa`
- `http://localhost:63428/dav/asdadsa/asdasd`
- `http://localhost:63428/dav/asdadsa/a%20%20sdasd`  (with space in the url)
But if I try with theese:
- `http://localhost:63428/dav/asdadsa.docx`
- `http://localhost:63428/dav/asdads/a.docx`
My handler not called and the server return with 404. I thought that the wildcard will match every url which start with `dav/`.
Any idea how to achive that the urls with extensions also match to my route?

UPDATE:
I found this [page](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx).
It's set from config, not from code behind but don't have to set the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests settings and unfortunately don't get the route values so clean that in my original example.
Maybe somebody will be intrested if come to this question for answers.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156204/can-someone-explain-asp-net-routing-syntax-to-me/8796350#8796350

Comment: Unfortunately that link not answer for my question. First approach I want to handle the entire url after the dav segment (parse and process). And my rount not working only if there is a extension in the end of my url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following configuration to your web.config file then your routing will include files as well.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
      <!-- more -->
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

One different solution is to add `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` but that gives an overhead in that all your registered HTTP modules run on every request, not just managed requests (e.g. .aspx). This means modules will run on every .jpg .gif .css .html .pdf etc.

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) about the different routing settings.

Just remember, if you're adding your special routing to the existing routing you have to add your routing first or it won't be processed, as in this example.

```
Route route = new Route("dav/{*Pathinfo}", new CustomHandler());
routes.Add(route);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

One problem with this approach is that the first route definition confuses Html helpers in your system so you won't any longer get nice routes like `localhost/home/index` but instead `localhost/dav?action=index&controller=home`. The solution to this is to restrict the first route to only be valid on incoming route requests. This can be done by creating a `RouteConstraint` and add it to the route definition in a `RouteValueDictionary`.

```
public class OnlyIncomingRequestConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can then redefine your route definition in this way:

```
Route route = new Route("dav/{*Pathinfo}", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = new OnlyIncomingRequestConstraint() }), new CustomHandler());
routes.Add(route);
```

After this your default routes should be back to normal again.

Comment: First of all it works!However I'm concerned a little bit about this option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX#sectionToggle11  
It's independend from ui, so currently my code is from a webforms application.  
I do not understand this: "When runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is true, a URL like http://mysite/myapp/home goes to ASP.NET, even though there is no .aspx, .mvc, or similar extension on the URL." this example works right now without the settings.  
Another thing:"Note that this will add some overhead to requests."  
And lastly. How do I set this programatically?

Comment: That quote simply means that ALL paths are being sent to the routing engine. I've updated my example a little so it won't add that extra overhead (well, not that much anyway)...had to do some reading first.

Comment: Can't put this kind a route at start. It's catch all url generation and give urls like this: http://localhost:50841/dav?action=Index&controller=Home

Comment: Check the new update at the bottom of the answer. I think I solved your last problem.

Comment: Works cool. Even if I generate Url for files: @Url.RouteUrl("davReq",new { url = "a/b/c.doc" }) The only confusing think that the RouteConstraint is never called. I put breakpoint int the Match method and my code never braked.

Comment: It's strange that it never breaks, it should, I think. But I'm glad it's working for you :-)

Comment: Ok. I solved the puzzle...half at least :) Check int the GetHttpHandler method of the CusomHandler. The requestContext.RouteData.Route.Constraints is null. It seems this also work but it's beyond my understanding: new Route("dav/{*url}", new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = null as IRouteConstraint }), new CustomHandler());

Comment: Fully understand: You call the wrong overload. The second parameter in that case will be the "defaults" parameter. If you put a null as second parameter: Route route = new Route("dav/{*url}", null, new RouteValueDictionary(new { irrelevant = new OnlyIncomingRequestConstraint() }), new CustomHandler()); But in this way I can't generate Url-s for files using the route: @Url.RouteUrl("davReq",new { url = "a/b/c.doc" })