# How to ignore route which contains ".php" extention

Tags: c#, routes

I want to ignore all *.php requests to my server.

Now I can ignore .php requests on the root

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.php");
```

How to ignore there requests everywhere, like this:

```
www.site.com/products/index.php
www.site.com/clients/africa/info.php
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.routecollection.ignore?view=netframework-4.8.1&redirectedfrom=MSDN#overloads) following would work

```
routes.Ignore("{*allphp}", new {allphp=@".*\.php(/.*)?"});
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("*/{resource}.php");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be "*{resource}.php" ? so that it gets php pages that are in the root as well?

Comment: try this routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.php/{*pathInfo}"); and see this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156204/can-someone-explain-asp-net-routing-syntax-to-me